# is it possible to use hibernate projections on static methods?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

consider this query:

```
@Query(" Select sum(profit.amount) from Profit profit")
double sumProfit();
```

We can also use optional

```java
@Query(" Select sum(profit.amount) from Profit profit")
Optional<Double> sumProfit();
```

But if we try to use `OptionalDouble` it won't work

And to use projections we can't use `java.util.DoubleOptional(sum(amount))` as `DoubleOptional` constructor is private.

So I'm curious about the possibility of using projections on static method so my query will be similar to this:

```java
@Query(" Select java.util.OptionalDouble.of(sum(profit.amount)) from Profit profit")
double sumProfit();
```

Comment: You typed the code already I suggest run it and you will know... However I don't see the use of an optional here as if there is nothing, for the `sum` it will return 0. So it will always return a result.

Comment: already tried Select java.util.OptionalDouble.of(sum(profit.amount)) from Profit profit and it won't work but I was wondering if I am doing something wrong or if there a workaround for it. I know that sum will return 0, but the need of optional to make use of it's existing methods

Comment: But `Optional` or `OptionalDouble` doesn't add anything (but complexity). Well as you noticed it doesn't work so no you are not doing anything wrong it doesn't work, it will only work with `Optional` as a return type (which Spring Data will wrap automatically). But as stated apart from complexity to your code it won't add anything.